# Show appmenu even when the top panel is not mouse overed

Tags: 11.04, unity, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can auto-hide for the application menu be turned off in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity)

I would like to know if there's any way i can keep the appmenu ( "File", "Edit", "help", etc ) displayed on Unity's top panel while i have focus on the app, without having to hover the top panel for the menu to be displayed.

In other words, always show the appmenu of the current focused window no matter what the app window size is ( like mac osx).

Thanks

Comment: is the global menu the same thing than the appmenu? I believe global menu refers to the ubuntu icon on the left top corner, while appmenu refers to the app specific options

Comment: The right term is "application menu". We don't call it the global menu because there's an older project that was named that that is sort of the same thing. I've renamed the duped question to make more sense. (the button you refer to is called the home button btw)

Answer (score 0):

Make it stick I don't think. I just use Alt+F Alt+E .....