# How to disable auto-hiding of the application's menu in top panel?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can auto-hide for the application menu be turned off in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity)

Unity comes with features from Mac OS X, but one of them is modified and is very frustrating me.
When you open any application, you can see only title of it in the top panel.
But after you move mouse to the panel, menu of the application is displayed - Why menu can't be displayed always as in OS X ? Everytime I want to select some item from menu, I have to move with cursor to panel, then read menu items and then I can select something...
I would be very glad when I could reconfigure this behavior.
Thanks