# 11.04 unity top bar configuration

Tags: 11.04, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can auto-hide for the application menu be turned off in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity)

Hi all,

Is there any way to modify the top bar behaviour in Unity ?

As I have read around - not...

What i'm looking for is:
I want to see the "File,  Edit, View, ..." menu **all the time** instead of the filename title in it... filename title is really useless...

Any help with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. This is as is...

You get the 'file' etc only when you have the desktop active. Otherwise this part of the panel is used by the currently active item (browser-> title, USC->usc options etc etc).

Comment: I hope to see an update from Canonical giving some 'open-source' freedom and flexibility for Unity

Answer (score 0):

If you just click on the destop first the menu will be available in the top panel.