# Always show Global Menu?

Tags: unity, panel, menu, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can auto-hide for the application menu be turned off in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity)

Hi all,
i was wondering if it's possible to have Global Menu always showing the full menu?
At the moment, Global menu only shows the menu when hovering over the top panel.

Thanks!

Comment: the most annoying "feature" of 11.04

Comment: I could get on board with a global menu, but the fact that you have to scrub the top of the screen merely to discover it is a massive show stopper.