# Disable auto-hide for the global application menu in Unity

Tags: unity, 11.10, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can auto-hide for the application menu be turned off in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity)

In Ubuntu 11.04 auto-hide of global application menu was [impossible to turn off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity), what about Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: perhaps a combination of gnome classic plus Docky is what you are after?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic