# How to permanently unhide the application menu?

Tags: appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can auto-hide for the application menu be turned off in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity)

Why is the application menu appears only on "mouse on"? How to disable autohide option for all programs?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 before you log in. If you only want to deactivate it or enable it for a single application, then you can do things like `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 gcalctool`. Use 1 instead of 0 to enable.