# Is it possible to disable auto hide in the global menu?

Tags: unity, globalmenu, autohide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can auto-hide for the application menu be turned off in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity)

Is there a way to disable the global menu from automatically hiding in Unity? I would like if the menus behaved in the same way as they did in Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1):

No ,currently it is imposiible