# How to show hidden menu items in the menu bar?

Tags: 12.04, unity, thunderbird, appmenu, menu-bar

In Unity, the menu bar for most applications appears on the top panel, on mouse-over. Additionally, one can use the keyboard to quickly access menu items by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> and typing what you're looking for.

The mouse-over menu, however, hides some items. Is there any way to get these to be shown, all the time? (Is this bug?)

The only example I know of (and they're *hard* to discover, because you can't enumerate choices from the <kbd>alt</kbd> finder, and you can't easily see what's missing from the menu itself) is the entire "Format" menu in Thunderbird. It resides under Options → Format, or so claims the <kbd>alt</kbd> finder.

Note that this question pertains to *the items within the menu* **not** the menu bar itself; specifically, this is not the same question as "[Can auto-hide for the application menu be turned off in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity)" which is referring to the bar as a whole and not items within it — the answer there is unrelated to this question. I don't wish to enable/disable auto-hiding of the entire *bar*, rather, I seek to know why some items (such as the aforementioned Options → Format) do not appear in the menu.

Comment: Duplicate fail. This is *not* a duplicate. I'm well aware of *where* the menu is, and as much as its position annoys me, that isn't what the question is about. I'm asking about **menu items** that should show up, but don't: they only appear when searching for them via `alt`.

Comment: Not duplicate. I have experimented this behavior recently in 15.10 (and continues in 16.04) where the whole menu is missing, and you cannot bring it up with either the mouse or the <kbd>alt</kbd> key. The menu is neither in the global top bar nor in the application window.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity it is called `Global-menu`.Application menu shows on the Unity panel instead of on the application window itself.If you want to disable it,please follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu).This should solve your problem