# Can I show the global menu on all displays?

Tags: unity, 13.04, globalmenu

Let's say I have a two monitor setup.

I open Firefox on display #1. If I hover my mouse to select a menu item on display #1, the global menu will show. But if I hover the mouse to select a menu item on display #2 nothing will show, unless I move the Firefox window to the second display. But then the global menu will not show on display #1.

Can I make the global menu show on all displays, no matter on which display the application is visble?

Please note that I do not want to [disable the auto-hide feature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity).

***Edit: Adding a reason on why I need this:***

One of the reasons I ask for this, is because I regularly connect my laptop to my TV Set and watch movies (I use VLC). So, most of the times I want to access the menu of VLC without the need of interrupting the playback.

And even if I did interrupt the playback, VLC's playlist can be undocked from the main window, and become a window on its own.

So I always keep the playlist on the laptop display, and the movie on full screen on the TV display. And even if the playlist is the active window, since VLC's main window is on the TV display, the menu would only show on the TV display, and not on the laptop.

Comment: I can't figure out how can be VLC's playlist undocked from the main window. Can you?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Yeah, sure. In VLC's menu go to `Tools`. In it, there is an menu option called `Docked playlist`. Uncheck it.

Comment: I found it. For me *Dock playlist* is in *View* (I use VLC media player 2.0.6). Now, as you can check the problem is that the Playlist doesn't have any kind of menu when the focus is on it (appearing only *VLC media player* in global menu) indifferent in which display is the Playlist window. So this is a problem with Playlist menu (you can [report it like a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121)) and nothing to do with global menu. As an alternative, **you can use the VLC menu from notification area** (system tray) which is visible in every display, indifferent where is VLC window.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't (only if someone will make an application/program to do so or if you select *Mirror displays* in *System settings* > *Hardware* > *Displays*). The thing you're asking is *inconsistent*.

Think that you have one application (Firefox) opened on the display #1 and another one (let say Chromium) on the display #2. Now, you look at the display #2, so you use Chromium and you will see in global menu the menu for Chromium. What reason do you have now to see in global menu the menu for Firefox that is displayed on display #1? And vice versa. *This makes no sense...*

Comment: I'm not saying you are not right, but this is not an answer to the question, should be posted as a comment?

Comment: The global menu is supposed to be shown for the activated application. If I'm using Firefox, and Chromium is on the other screen, I still want to see the Firefox menu since it's the application I'm using.

Comment: @Dan *"The global menu is supposed to be shown for the activated application"* **on the display where you are using the respective application**. I think that the global menu is a "child" process of the display, not the other way.

Comment: @Nanne I am sorry for a neggative answer, but this is the answer.

Comment: After your edits it does look more like an answer indeed, the comment was ofcourse aimed at your answer before your edits....

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I edited the question to shed some light on a reason behind this, and to explain why this would make sense.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I don't think you're right about it being inconsistent. In your example, the current behavior is to show Chromium's menu on display #2 and an _empty_ bar on display #1. Implementation details aside, there's conceptually no reason the empty bar couldn't be replaced with another copy of Chromium's menu.

Comment: @ændrük Conceptual, the global menu it shows you a menu with what you have in front (the application on which you are focused) on the current display. See [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/305674/can-i-show-the-global-menu-on-all-displays/306739?noredirect=1#comment386444_306739).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Yes, that is what it does, and this is a question about making it do something different.

Comment: @ændrük No, the question is "*Can I show the global menu on all displays?*" and the short answer is "*no*". Or, as I said, we can wait someone to make a script/application/program to do so. Unlikely to see that will happen.

Answer (score 0):

If dosn't matter in wich screen apper firefox you can duplicate screen so you will be able to see the same in bouth screens.

Sorry for my speling

Comment: That's mirrored displays, I do not want that.