# How to disable autohide in global menu?

Tags: globalmenu

I am using the newest version of Ubuntu 14.04 and I like the global menu bar feature but I want the menus to always be visible not only when I hover my mouse over it. Is there a way to do that? Because the menus (like File, Edit, View etc.) disappear as soon as you move your mouse away from the menu bar at the top... :( Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: I think this [Link][1]  has the answer for your question 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity

Comment: That looks like it is for 12.04 not 14.04...

Comment: It is the same question.  At best you can only slow down the autohide - you cannot disable it as one of the answers explains.